# Define a function count_down() that consumes a number a produces a string counting down to 1

Tags: python, list

Define a function count_down() that consumes a number a produces a string counting down to 1.

```
count_down(3) => "3, 2, 1"
count_down(0) => ""  
count_down(1) => "1"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: `range()`, `str()` and `join()` - use it.

Comment: Specifically, you should check out [how to ask homework questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution could look like

```
def count_down(n):
    return ', '.join(str(i) for i in range(n, 0, -1))
    # return ', '.join(map(str, range(n, 0, -1)))

>>> count_down(5)
'5, 4, 3, 2, 1'
```

[`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str), [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) are very fundamental functions/methods you should read up on in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/contents.html).